# Handling java.util.concurrent.Future with null result

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

If I submit task, and futureTask.get() returns null, I would like to process what I sent in the Callable object another way.  When debugging, I can see that my Future has a private final member called "sync".  "sync" contains my callable, which has the original data that I sent in the Callable. Unfortunately, I can't get to it.

In pseudocode...

```
Callable callable = new Callable(myData);

Future future = executor.submit(callable);

if (future.get() == null)
{
     //what I would like to have if the "sync" member was available..
      String alreadySubmittedData = future.sync.callable.myData;
 }
```

It seems like there should be a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Callable` and `Future` are just interfaces anyway, so I guess you have to keep that info around yourself (e.g. associating futures to callables in a map).

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't get myData from your variable callable?

Comment: Consider posting this question about the question as a comment instead of an answer